# What is the most robust javascript UI framework that plays nicely with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, frameworks

After reading [this active post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs) I decided to commit to jQuery as my go-to javascript framework.

Now I am trying to decide which UI framework to learn in combination with my jQuery efforts.  Before I default to jQuery UI, I thought I'd ask for feedback from more experienced developers.

I am looking for a framework that is:

- Stable across browsers (both new and slightly old)
- Actively developed
- Highly flexible
- Packed with featured
- Well documented
- Supported by a strong community

Two questions given the list of considerations above:

1. Does someone have a definitive list of the options worth considering?
2. Is there any reason not to use jQuery UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQueryUI is limited in scope and functionality; it kind if depends of what type of UI components you need. There are definitely loads of plugins available, but their quality is *highly* variable, and altering their behavior is often frustrating.

If you're looking for a full GUI environment I'd probably look elsewhere, if you just need some simple interaction, and you're comfortable modifying things when they don't suit your needs, it's pretty nice.